# How to do a linear regression with variable coefficients?

Tags: python, math, statistics

I'm trying to make a linear regression on an equation that has variable coefficients. Let's say I have a bunch of results: F,H,T and M. I know I can link them with the following equations:

- F = a*H + b*T
- M = b*H + c*T

a, b and c are not constants and are functions of H and T. I can easily create a Scikit Learn model to predict F and M from H and T. It is working well.

My trouble now is: how could I extract a, b and c to get their values along H and T? In a more mathematical way, how is it possible to make such kind of regression? The problem is that I have 2 equations for 3 parameters. With a specific set of F, H, T, M, I am not able to calculate a, b and c. But as they must be continuous, I am pretty sure it is possible to deduct them with enough inputs. Maybe some statistical tool would be able to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to fit a general linear model, in other words trying to fit the model$$Y=XB+U$$where$$Y=\left[\begin{array}{c}F\M\end{array}\right], X=[H,T]$$, $U$ is the error and $B$ are the coefficients. Scikit learn can easily tell you the coefficients, but you have the additional constraint that you want the matrix $B$ to be symmetric, which makes things harder. I'm not aware of a scikit learn functionality for this, but I think R has a package called glmc (http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~handcock/combining/software/glmc.html) which might be able to do what you want.

Comment: Having coefficient symetric is not necessary. I just want to be able to export them. And I would like to plot for example a function of T.

Comment: And how to do that in scikit learn? Could you give me an example?

Comment: Ah, since you don't need symmetric coefficients (in which case the parameter b in your equation for M should have another name, it's easy.
You let X be your independent variable matrix, you let Y be your dependent variable matrix, then run

`reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, Y);

B = reg.coef_`

The matrix B will have your coefficients.

Comment: ok that's a good start. But the problem is that i can't apply a linear regression because coefficients are non linear. Let's consider only the equation: M = bH + cT.
in this case, i want to determine b and c considering that b = f(H) and c = g(T).
It makes the problem a bit trickier.

Comment: I don't see why this is a problem for linear regression. Whenever you fit a linear regression model, the coefficients are learned as a function of the data, and that function is nonlinear (e.g. least squares). What matters is that the dependent variable and independent variable are linearly related (which they are in your case) and then the algorithm learns the coefficients.

Comment: That's what I was talking about. X and Y are not linearly linked and that's why I don't want to use a linear regression. Using reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, Y); B = reg.coef_ will approximate b and c constant, which they are not. They are a function of H and T.
I mean, b could be for example 6 if H>2, 1.5H² if H<2. I want scikit learn to give me the possibility to plot b in function of H like I would do with the formulation above.
Maybe I'm not clear enough or I didn't get your explanation.